# How to use a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

make formula work in VBA

```
"=IF(LEFT(VLOOKUP(J2,A:H,8,FALSE),1)=B,S,B)"
```

Comment: Emmm, you're missing quotes around "B", "S", and "B", and you'll need to double up quotes if  you're using the formula in VBA.

Comment: thanks, you are right, double quotes work